# LED-color HTC Legend

Tags: android, led

I'm trying to make the LED of the HTC Legend color blue along with my notification.

```
    notif.ledARGB = color.BLUE; 
    notif.ledOnMS = 100;
    notif.ledOffMS = 100;
    notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

The led just keeps flashing green (and not in the requested pattern). Is there something wrong with the code or doesn't the Legend support controlling the LED?

Comment: Have you tried unplugging it from the usb?  The LED won't flash if the usb is plugged in.  You cannot debug while trying to flash the LED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the HTC Hero and the HTC Nexus One had their LED's locked to only one color in the stock build so the Legend is probably too.

The hardware is (most likely, as Hero/N1) capable of full color so future updates (or custom ROMS) will/may unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Legend even on sale anywhere yet?  You may not be running a final version of the Legend software.

Or it may be that HTC decided not to add support for multicolor notification lights for some reason.  A similar problem is present on the Nexus One, I believe it always flashes white no matter what color you request, even though the hardware is capable of doing multiple colors.

Comment: In Holland the Legend is indeed on sale.

It could be possible that HTC decided to not add the support for custom notification-lights. But i can't find any specifications on that...

Comment: ask htc themselves - androidsupport@htc.com